# Dynamically generating widgets from json data without performance losses

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is the problem I'm trying to solve: generating a form from a variable set of widgets where the exact widgets and their ordering is directed by the data, namely schema. The first approach I've taken looks like (omitting the unnecessary details):

controller.js:

```
 angular.module('app').controller(function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    actions: [{
      name: 'Action1',
      base: 'nova.create_server',
      baseInput: {
        flavorId: {
          title: 'Flavor Id',
          type: 'string'
        },
        imageId: {
          title: 'Image Id',
          type: 'string'
        }
      },
      input: [''],
      output: [{
          type: 'string',
          value: ''
        }, {
          type: 'dictionary',
          value: {
            key1: '',
            key2: ''
          }
        }, {
          type: 'list',
          value: ['', '']
        }]
    }]
  };

  $scope.schema = {
    action: [{
      name: 'name',
      type: 'string',
    }, {
      name: 'base',
      type: 'string',
    }, {
      name: 'baseInput',
      type: 'frozendict',
    }, {
      name: 'input',
      type: 'list',
    }, {
      name: 'output',
      type: 'varlist',
    }
    ]
  };
})
```

template.html

```
      <div ng-controller="actionCtrl" ng-repeat="item in data.actions">
        <div ng-repeat="spec in schema.action" ng-class="{'right-column': $even && isAtomic(spec.type), 'left-column': $odd && isAtomic(spec.type)}">
           <typed-field></typed-field>
           <div class="clearfix" ng-show="$even"></div>
        </div>
      </collapsible-panel>
```

directives.js

```
.directive('typedField', function($http, $templateCache, $compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      $http.get(
        '/static/mistral/js/angular-templates/fields/' + scope.spec.type + '.html',
        {cache: $templateCache}).success(function(templateContent) {
          element.replaceWith($compile(templateContent)(scope));
        });
    }
  }
})
```

Among the templates located inside '/fields/' the simplest possible template for the string-type field is

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>{$ spec.title || makeTitle(spec.name) $}</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="item[spec.name]">
</div>
```

This approach works for - all the widgets are rendered, model bindings work, but on once I type a single letter inside of these widgets, the scope changes and the widgets are redrawn, causing:
 * focus losing
 * some time delay effective meaning poor performance.

Trying to overcome this drawback, I've rewritten my app in the following way:

template.html

```
      <div ng-controller="actionCtrl" ng-repeat="item in data.actions">
        <action></action>
      </div>
```

directives.js

```
.directive('typedField', function($http, $templateCache, idGenerator, $compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    compile: function ($element, $attrs) {
      $http.get(
        '/static/mistral/js/angular-templates/fields/' + $attrs.type + '.html',
        {cache: $templateCache}).success(function (templateContent) {
          $element.replaceWith(templateContent);
        });
      return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.title = $attrs.title;
        scope.type = $attrs.type;
        scope.name = $attrs.name;
      }
    }
  }
})

.directive('action', function($compile, schema, isAtomic) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
      angular.forEach(
        schema.action,
        function(spec, index) {
            var cls = '', elt;
            if ( isAtomic(spec.type) ) {
              cls = index % 2 ? 'class="right-column"' : 'class="left-column"';
            }
            elt = '<div ' + cls + '><typed-field type="' + spec.type + '" name="' + spec.name + '"></typed-field>';
            if ( index % 2 ) {
              elt += '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
            }
            elt += '</div>';
            tElement.append(elt);
        });
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Instead of getting schema from scope, I'm providing it via dependency injection into compile phase of a directive (which is run only the first time - which seemed quite the thing I needed to avoid repetitive full redraw of widgets). But now instead of nicely looking widgets (as before) I get raw html with data bindings not evaluated at all. I guess that I'm doing something wrong, but fail to graps how should I correctly use the compile function to avoid performance issues. Could you please give an advice on what should be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found out what should be returned from the directive's compile function in that case

```
  .directive('action', function($compile, schema, isAtomic) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
        angular.forEach(
          schema.action,
          function(spec, index) {
            var cls = '', elt;
            if ( isAtomic(spec.type) ) {
              cls = index % 2 ? 'class="right-column"' : 'class="left-column"';
            }
            elt = '<div ' + cls + '><typed-field type="' + spec.type + '" name="' + spec.name + '"></typed-field>';
            if ( index % 2 ) {
              elt += '<div class="clearfix"></div>';
            }
            elt += '</div>';
            tElement.append(elt);
         });
         var linkFns = [];
         tElement.children().each(function(tElem) {
           linkFns.push($compile(tElem));
         });
         return function(scope) {
           linkFns.forEach(function(linkFn) {
             linkFn(scope);
           });
         }
      }
   }
})
```

What actually $compile does is calling the 'compile' function of each directive it encounters - thus calling $compile on current directive's template lead to infinite recursion, but calling it for each child of this directive worked fine.